# select one radio button from each row and then submit it to database mysqli

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysqli

```
    <?php
    include('connect.php');
    $query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from users") or die("unable to connect");

    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
        <body>


            <h2 align="center"> student list</h2>
            <form action="radio.php" method="post"> 
            <table align="center" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="700">
                <thread>
                    <td align='center'>id</td>
                    <td align='center'>enrolloment_no</td>
                    <td align='center'>first_name</td>
                    <td align='center'>last_name</td>
                    <td align='center'>attendance&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>

                        </thread>

            <?php
                $i=1;
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_BOTH))
                    {
                    echo "<tr>
                    <td align='center'>".@$i."</td>

<td align='center'>".@$row['enrolloment_no']."</td>
<td align='center'>".@$row['first_name']."</td>
<td align='center'>".@$row['last_name']."</td>
<td align='center'>


<input type=\"radio\" name=\"a\" value=\"present\">present

<input type=\"radio\" name=\"a\" value=\"absent\">absent

</tr>

";
            $i++;
                        }   

                ?>

                </table>
                <input type="submit" value="submit">
                        </form>
                </body>



        </html>
```

The above mentioned code contains a attendance page form which contains radio buttons but the main problem in the above code is i am unable to select radio button from each row as i need to select radio button from each row that is either student would be present or absent so please if anyone has any suggestions how to select one radio button either present or absent from each row and then submit to database.

Comment: you mean when you click a radio button it wont mark the radio?

Comment: Why are you "unable to select radio button from each row"?  What actually prevents you from doing this?  What happens when you try?

Comment: if i would click on radio button at a time only one button is been selected from whole column but as i am preparing an  attendance page so for each student i would need to click either present or absent but its not working only one radio button is been selected from whole column i.e. i can only select present from whole column .

Comment: So make each row has inputs with the same name diff of others

Comment: sir can you please edit me in my code and share it with me .????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a number increasing by each row, or better, set this integer equal to the row's corresponding identifier in your database.

Add a hidden input with name="rowIDs[]" & value="{theIdentifier}".

When you set the name of your row's radio button to "a_{theIdentifier}" you can run a foreach in your PHP script.

might this be what you are looking for?

global example in your code:

```
 $i=1;
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_BOTH)){
       echo "<tr>
       <td align='center'>".@$i."</td>
       <td align='center'>".@$row['enrolloment_no']."</td>
       <td align='center'>".@$row['first_name']."</td>
       <td align='center'>".@$row['last_name']."</td>
       <td align='center'>
         <input type=\"hidden\" value=\"".$row['enrolloment_no']."\" name=\"rowIDs[]\" />
         <input type=\"radio\" name=\"a_".$row['enrolloment_no']."\" value=\"present\">present
         <input type=\"radio\" name=\"a_".$row['enrolloment_no']."\" value=\"absent\">absent
       </td>
       </tr>
       ";
       $i++;
   }
```

Now in the submission:

```
$rowIDs = $_POST['rowIDs'];
foreach($rowIDs as $rowID) {
   $radioButtonValue = $_POST['a_'.$rowID];
   mysqli_query("update `yourtable` SET `attendance` = '".$radioButtonValue."' WHERE `enrolloment_no` = '".$rowID."'");
}
```

(to do this, replace $i by $row['enrolloment_no'])

ps i made some mistakes i just edited.

When you add these inputs on the top of the form, or bottom.. but IN the form tags
 Present
 Absent
Use master attendance
Then in the submission php part:

```
if(isset($_POST['useMasterAttendance'])) {
  $masterAttendanceValue = $_POST["masterAttendance"];
  $rowIDs = $_POST['rowIDs'];
  foreach($rowIDs as $rowID) {

     mysqli_query("update `yourtable` SET `attendance` = '".$masterAttendanceValue."' WHERE `enrolloment_no` = '".$rowID."'");
  }
}else {
//DO THE CODE FOR EACH ROW LIKE ABOVE
}
```

Sorry if i made any typos

Comment: Thank you sir my work is been done. now sir can you help me how can i can submit these values in database.

Comment: if you replace $i, by the $row['enrollment_no']. Then you can update the database using the $row['enrollment_no']. I guess this is your key for the database?

Comment: See the edit i just made. If this is your solution please up-vote and mark it as your solution.

Comment: sir thats been done now can i insert a radio button at top with the help of which i can select all the students are present or other radio button absent which means all students are absent.if you could just help me out in this stuff..

Comment: Oh thats great sir thank you so much for separing you time.... If any query i would ask in further replyss...

Comment: Your welcome, if this was all you needed, then please upvote and mark this as answer

Comment: Yes as soon as the output is obtained i would surely do it.